# Unable to Configure Pop-Ups in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, arcgis-portal

A particular map of mine published to arcgis portal is not allowing me to configure pop-ups. I can enable the pop-ups but when i click 'configure' nothing happens what-so-ever.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the table data needs to be coming from a verified data source in arcgis. Once i moved the table to my connected database i was able to configure the pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this sort of problem before, it actually had to do with the layers that are being used in the webmap. They have to be feature layers if I remember correctly. Try uploading the shapefiles as zip files and then that will create the layers for you and then you will be able to see the popup.